# My javascript form validation works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

The javascript:

```
    function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["newsletter"]["agree"].value;
    if (newsletter.agree.checked != 1)
    {
        alert("Checkbox must be checked");
        return false;
    }


    var y=document.forms["newsletter"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=y.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=y.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=y.length)
    {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;   
    }

    else 
    {   
        return true;
    }
}
```

And my HTML

```
<div id="signup">
<form id="newsletter" action="" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<fieldset>
<p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="35"/>
Please send me the monthly newsletter 
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="agree" value=""/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Signup"/></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div><!-- signup -->
```

When I click submit with invalid entries in Chrome, the alert messages show and the form doesn't submit. However, when I do the same in Firefox, the form submits without an alert message.

I've been working on this for 5 hours, I truly have no idea. Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can't figure it out after 5 hours of banging your head on it, **take a break.**

Comment: your two blocks of code is running perfectly here, would you provide full source in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might help you.

```
<div id="signup">
        <form id="newsletter" action="" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <fieldset>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="35"/>
        Please send me the monthly newsletter 
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="agree" id="agree" value=""/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Signup"/></p>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div><!-- signup -->



   function validateForm()
    {
        var agreeEl = document.getElementById("agree");
        if (agreeEl.checked != 1)
        {
            alert("Checkbox must be checked");
            return false;
        }


        var emailEl = document.getElementById("email");
        var atpos = emailEl.value.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = emailEl.value.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= y.length) {
          alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;   
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Nope, the script still doesn't work in Firefox. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Which version of Firefox do you user? I've tested it on Firefox 10.0.1 . UPD: I updated Firefox to 12.0 and it works fine too. Please, give us more information.

Comment: Firefox 12. My friend, who is also using 12.0, is having the same problem.

EDIT: When I click signup in Firefox with the error console open it shows an error as newsletter not defined.

Comment: Did you realy test my code? Because I didn't use global variable of the form('newsletter') like you. I added identifiers for each field and get their values by id. Please, copy-paste my code(html and javascript) to your project and test. It should work properly.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry, you're right. I was was missing an id attribute for email so when it was looking for an id, nothing was there. 

Thanks so much for this answer!

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, is there some reason you are using 'get' instead of 'post' to submit your form? Chrome complains to me when I tried to submit your form using 'get'.

I setup a simple fiddle to test your form at http://jsfiddle.net/jsWyw/.  Everything works fine if I use JQuery to handle the form submit instead of your 'onSubmit'.  So I looked into what was going on with onSubmit and came across this thread: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Z3MD5Od3oQM.

Things to try:

- Make sure to use post instead of get
- Use 'onSubmit' instead of 'onsubmit'
- Make sure your script is included using `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>`

If that fails, I would suggest handling the `submit` event yourself in Javascript instead of using `onSubmit` which seems to be a bit flaky in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks. I might just try handling it with JavaScript instead of using the html onsubmit or onclick attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at your error console?  Your validateForm handler is assuming that `window.newsletter` is a form element (instead of using document.forms["newsletter"] in that first `if()`), which it's not in Firefox in standards mode.  So that line throws, and if an onsubmit handler throws the form will just go ahead and submit.  But of course the error console is reporting that the handler threw.....

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand, could you, perhaps, further explain please?

Comment: Replace `newsletter.agree.checked` with `document.forms["newsletter"]["agree"].checked`

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
}


<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```